# Apache Virtual Hosting redirects to default domain rather than loading the correct domain (raspi)

Tags: apache, virtualhost, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to host 2 websites, using 2 legitimate domains that are registered and are indeed working, my issue is that when I try to load the second domain it redirects to the first one instead of loading the second. (for example, I have google1.com and google2.com, when I access google2.com it redirects to google2.com)

this is the config for the second website (not using the real domain here)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain.xyz
        ServerAlias www.domain.xyz
        DocumentRoot /var/www/thewest
</VirtualHost>
```

sites-enabled is correct (using a2ensite)

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 May 12 11:10 default.conf -> ../sites-available/default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 May 12 12:01 thewest.conf -> ../sites-available/thewest.conf
```

and I've configured the directory on apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/thewest>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But this still happens. why though? 
EDIT: This is running on a Raspberry Pi using Raspbian, and I should also point out that I use a DDNS service.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Apache configuration file and make sure that the following line is added before the virtual host section:

```
NameVirtualHost *80
```

Don't forget to restart Apache for the changes to take effect.